# Create custom SnackBar class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a custom SnackBar widget for my flutter app so I can use it throughout the code.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomSnackBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String snackMessage;
  final Color snackColor;

  const CustomSnackBar(
      {super.key, required this.snackMessage, required this.snackColor});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SnackBar(
        content: const Center(
          child: Text(
            snackMessage,  <<<  ERROR HERE
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
          ),
        ),
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
          left: 10,
          right: 10,
        ),
        backgroundColor: snackColor,
      );
}
```

I get an error where I try to use snackMessage. Here is the error:

```
Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor.
```

How do I use the snackMessage to pass the message?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove const keyword in parent widget Center